# Unity3d - Управление персонажем с помощью touch (C#)

Tags: c#, unity3d, элементы-управления

Подскажите пожалуйста каким способом можно сделать управление выбранным персонажем (например кораблем в космосе), через touch (без использования каких - либо кнопок, просто пальцем на экране выбирая корабль). В Play Market есть игры в которых игроку дается возможность только управлять кораблем в ограниченной области, но корабль стреляет сам, т.е отсутствует надобность в добавлении кнопок стрельбы.
Я знаю что для Unity3d есть скрипты имитирующие Joystick, но они занимают место на экране и отвлекают если игроку не нужно стрелять.
Upd: похожее управление есть в играх типа space shooter

Comment: добавьте тэг C#, если вам интересна решение именно на шарпе

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Берешь **Joystick** любой, из стандартного ассета или из любого другого, делаешь область джостика на весь экран, берешь **Image** удаляешь спрайт, делаешь полностью прозрачным и вуаля.

Comment: Проверил, да в принципе получилось, но проблема в том что стик джойстика необходимо довольно сильно отдалять от управляемого объекта чтобы он перемещался, это мешает. Т.е я зажимаю курсор на объекте и начинаю елозить по всему экрану)

Comment: Увеличь чувствительность,  уменьши максимальный радиус отклонения джойстика от начальной точки касания. Сделай чтобы джойстик считал не от начальной точки, а от предыдущей. Да уйма вариантов. И это уже другой вопрос

Answer (score 0):

Для того чтобы сделать правильное управление необходимо точно представлять как вы хотите управлять объектами. Мы в своих проектах как правило по ряду причин используем самописные жесты, которые делают именно то что нам нужно